# Malthusian growth parameter is negative

Tags: mathematical-modeling, python

I'm trying to create python function that calculates the growth factor  (R) according to the Malthusian growth model
$$
X_{t+1} = R X_t
$$

The table I have is table with two countries population when each country has different growing factor that is given:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
R_1=0.962\\
R_2=0.997
\end{array}
$$
and both have the same initial population: 100M

I want to build function that calculates R between specific periods(years and months)  based on the population size of each contries every year.

My population table looks like this:

```
>>> year    pop1        pop2
0   0   1.000000e+08    1.000000e+08
1   1   9.620000e+07    9.970000e+07
2   2   9.254440e+07    9.940090e+07
3   3   8.902771e+07    9.910270e+07
4   4   8.564466e+07    9.880539e+07
```

And this is my function:

```
def find_r(df,init_pop,period,time_unit):
    res=[]
    
    if time_unit=='years':
        pop1=df.loc[df['year']==period].iloc[:,1]
        pop2=df.loc[df['year']==period].iloc[:,2]
        R1=pop1/init_pop
        res.append(R1)
        R2=pop2/init_pop
        res.append(R2)
    
    elif time_unit=='months':
        
        if 0<period<=12:
            
            pop1=((((df.loc[data['year']==1].iloc[:,1]).values)-((data.loc[data['year']==0].iloc[:,1]).values))/12)*period
            pop2=((((data.loc[data['year']==1].iloc[:,2]).values)-((data.loc[data['year']==0].iloc[:,2]).values))/12)*period
            R1=pop1/init_pop
            res.append(R1)
            R2=pop2/init_pop
            res.append(R2)
        else:
            print('to be continued')
            
    
    
    return(pd.DataFrame(res))
```

The problem: When I check for eyars for example and put year 1, seems like it works correct and I get the  correct R (0.962 aand 0.997), but when I run it for months (that are less than 1 year) I get negative results and that suprised me because I thought that if population shrinking I'll get less than 1 and for growing population I'll get greater than 1 but not negativ values.

For that reason I'm afriad the way I calculate it is wrong.

elaboratio nregard my calculation for months:
I reduce the inital population from the 1 year population. divide by 12 and then multiply by number of months -> to get the number of people after certain month

Then I take this number and divide it by the initial pop to get the R.

I have also tried to add the initial pop to pop1 calculation:

```
pop1=((((df.loc[data['year']==1].iloc[:,1]).values)-((data.loc[data['year']==0].iloc[:,1]).values))/12)+init_pop*period
            pop2=((((data.loc[data['year']==1].iloc[:,2]).values)-((data.loc[data['year']==0].iloc[:,2]).values))/12)+init_pop*period
```

but then I have gotten numbers like 6.55 ect. so I belive is also wrong,considering the trend of population shrinking.

Where am I wrong? is it the function that is bad or my logic?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you subtract the wrong values.

What you currently do is
$$
pop_1 = \left[pop(year=1)-pop(year=0)\right] \frac{period}{12}
\\
R_1 = \frac{pop_1}{init\_pop} 
$$

What you need to do is
$$
R_1 = \frac{pop(year=1)}{pop(year=0)}\frac{period}{12}
$$

Comment: thank you for your answer, from your answer I understand that I don't need to subtract, but I need to divide the pop of year1 by the pop of year 9 and then multiply it by the period/12, i'm not sure I understand that logic, if you could explain why I need to divide it and not to subtract. I still get with this weird numbers (e.g 4.00833e-09)